# in protobuf python api how to add element to nested message repeated property?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

```
message items {
    message require {
        optional bool require_sex = 1; //
        repeated int32 fate = 2 [packed = true];
    }
    optional int32 sub_type = 1;
    repeated int32 levels = 2 [packed = true];
}
```

I tried

```
raw.require.require_sex = 1
raw.require.fate.append(1)
raw.require.fate.extend([2,3])
```

got an error 
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'append'

but the first level repeated field works fine:

```
raw = down_pb2.items()
raw.levels.append(4)
```

is this kind of definition not supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a field using that *require* type and then access that field in the code.

```
message items {
    message require {
        optional bool require_sex = 1; //
        repeated int32 fate = 2 [packed = true];
    }
    optional int32 sub_type = 1;
    repeated int32 levels = 2 [packed = true];
    required require sub = 3;
}
```

then

```
raw.sub.fate.append(1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I really didn't noticed it's a TYPE not a variable. But the required limit is not really necessarily need here, optional can do the same thing here. Thanks again!